# Python - How to check if an variable is an number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build an ATM code , but I have another piece of code that is again proving troublesome.
Here is the error:

```
How Much Funds Do You Wish To Input Into Your Account? : £1565
Not A Vaild Amount
```

I am trying to make any integer be an acceptable answer, here is the code I created to check the answer:

```
def inputFunds(self):
    funds_input =(input("How Much Funds Do You Wish To Input Into Your Account? : £"))
    num_check = isinstance(funds_input, float)
    if num_check == "True" :
                         self.balance = self.balance + funds_input
                         print("Input Complete. Your New Balance is £" + self.balance)
    else:
        print("Not A Vaild Amount")
        tryagain =(input("Do You Wish To Try Again?"))
        if tryagain in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
            print(atm.inputFunds())
        else:
            back_menu =(input("Do You Wish To Go Back To The Menu? "))
            if back_menu in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
                print(atm.Menu())
            else:
                print(atm.End())
```

This is the last thing I need to make my code run smoothly.
Many Thanks.

***EDIT***

Having tried both the other answer that has been linked , and also the advice given below. My code still gives an syntax error to the 'except' statement.
Here is my code now:

```
    def inputFunds(self):
    try:
        funds_input = int(input("How Much Funds Do You Wish To Input Into Your Account? : £"))
        self.balance = self.balance + funds_input
        print("Your New Balance Is £" + str(self.balance)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not A Valid Amount")
        tryagain = input("Do You Wish To Try Again? ")
        if tryagain in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
            print(atm.inputFunds())
        else:
            back_menu = input("Do You Wish To Go Back To The Menu? ")
            if back_menu in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
                print(atm.Menu())
            else:
                print(atm.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do:

```
num_check = isinstance(funds_input, float)
```

because `input` always returns a string object.  `isinstance` is used only to test the type of an object, not to see if a string is a representation of another type.

Instead, you need to explicitly convert the input into a float:

```
funds_input = float(input("How Much Funds Do You Wish To Input Into Your Account? : £"))
```

Of course, you may also want to wrap this in a `try/except` to handle non-numerical inputs:

```
try:
    funds_input = float(input("How Much Funds Do You Wish To Input Into Your Account? : £"))
except ValueError:
    # Handle error
```

For more information, see: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761)

Comment: Hi @iCodez , thanks for your help. I just edited my question, if you can please look at it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the `print("Your New Balance Is £" + str(self.balance)` line.